# Integrated webcam consuming power even when unloaded

Tags: usb, power-management

I am using Manjaro i3. Usually my system's power consumption is about 4-5W (reported by `powertop`).

But, after I use my integrated webcam, the consumption increases and Integrated Webcam is the major contributor to that. I tried few things I saw on the internet, but it didn't fix the problem.

Output of `powertop`:

```
Power est.    Usage     Device name
  12.0 W     45.8%        CPU misc
  4.55 W    100.0%        USB device: Integrated_Webcam_HD (CN0VGCNHLOG008COA4RAA00)
  674 mW     45.8%        DRAM
  650 mW     45.8%        CPU core
```

(Sometimes it goes to `7+ W`)

I removed `uvcvideo` module using `modprobe`, but the usage didn't change. I ran `powertop --calibrate` and results are still the same.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

### Edit

```
Model: Dell XPS 15 9570, i7-8750H, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD
Kernel: 4.19.69-1-MANJARO
```

Comment: Please advise the make and model of your PC. Please obtain the model number from the sticker which has the serial number (just give the model number, please). Also please advise which Linux you use and which version number. Please click [edit] and add this info to your question; please don't use Add Comment, but instead click [edit].

Comment: I have seen the same happening with a realtek WiFi chipset, I had to cut it from a Raspberry clone board for it to stop causing power usage spikes even when not loading the firmware. Ask someone more knowledgeable with electronics to insert a manual switch or try another brand. I pretty much doubt this is a Unix problem, this is an hw problem.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thank you for your help, I edited my question to give more info about my hardware